# Formik validation errors are triggered despite data being entered

Tags: react-native, validation, formik, yup

The validation errors should only show when there are no data in the required fields. But for whatever reason, the errors always show regardless. I have also used "touched" and "setFieldTouched" props, but no luck so far. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here's my Yup validation scheme:

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required().label("Title"),
    price: Yup.number().required().label("Price"),
});
```

And my Formik form:

```js
<Formik
   validationSchema={validationSchema}
   initialValues={{ title: '', price: '' }}
   onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
      actions.resetForm();
      console.log(values);
   }}
>
   {(props) => (
      <View>
         <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
            <TextInput
               onBlur={()=>props.setFieldTouched("title")}
               style={styles.textInput} placeholder='title'
               onChangeText={(title)=>this.setState({title: title})}
               value={this.title} />
            
            {props.touched.title && <Text style={{ color: 'red', alignSelf: 'center'}}>{ props.errors.title}</Text>}
                            
            <TextInput
               onBlur={()=>props.setFieldTouched("price")}
               style={styles.textInput} placeholder='price'
               onChangeText={(price)=>this.setState({price: price})}
               value={this.price}
               keyboardType='numeric' />
           { props.touched.price && <Text style={{ color: 'red', alignSelf: 'center'}}>{ props.errors.price}</Text>}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
   )}
</Formik>
```

Here's a screenshot of the result:
[image]